# Problems due to sampling data from the same case patients multiple times?

Tags: predictive-models, case-control-study, oversampling

Please imagine the following scenario: In a predictive modeling task for the probability that a hospital patient will encounter a certain medical event, all available data is split into cases and controls. Controls are defined as having data (hospital discharges) before a certain date and no event up to now. Cases are defined as having any number of discharges anytime prior to an event.

The amount of patients in the case group is very small, which is why every single discharge of a patient of the case group is treated as a single sample in the dataset (essentially making multiple similar patients out of one with the only difference being the time until event encounter). For the control group, there are many more potential patients, which is why a random subset is used, balancing cases to controls at approximately 1:3. Controls also have all of their discharges treated as individual samples, but >80% only have one discharge.

**Now my questions**: What problems could arise from having case patients with more discharges more often in the data? How grave would they be? And what can be done to circumvent these potential issues? I would also be grateful for relevant literature to read up on this.

This is my notion of potential problems: A predictive algorithm might learn general clues of sickness (assuming that the number of discharges is a proxy for sickness) instead of specific predictors of the event as the amount of discharges correlates heavily with the event label. This might be dampened by giving more weight to type 2 error.